# Ubunty Bootable USB to ISO

Tags: usb, live-usb

I am using a Windows laptop (don't have access to Ubuntu device yet).

I have however an Ubuntu Bootable USB which is tested and works.

My laptop has a problem booting from USB, so i am trying to convert the USB to a CD so I can boot it from my windows laptop.

Could you please advise?  ty!!!

Comment: If laptop is so old as to not boot from USB, it probably needs Lubuntu or other lightweight Linux versions. Or if just not working, you may need to go into BIOS/UEFI and change setting to allow booting from USB port(s). Some also only boot from USB2 even if you have USB3.

Answer (score 1):

> so i am trying to convert the USB to a CD

That is not going to work: The installer will not fit on a CD; a DVD is required if you want it on a disk.

To create an ISO from an USB:

```
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=image.iso
```

where I assume `sdb` is your USB disk and this will create the file `image.iso` inside `~/Downloads`. *Please be careful with this* and ensure it is the correct device.

It might be easier/quicker to re-download the installer and burn that installer to a DVD though.